# Coordinates of current mouse position on leaflet map with shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I want to access the current mouse position in a leaflet map in shiny. When using shiny you can get  the current coordinates of a click event using `input$MAPID_click`, which contains latitude and longitude of the click. Similarly I want to have `input$MAPID_mouseover` with a list of the current latitude and longitude of the mouse cursor.

`mapview::addMouseCoordinates(map)` displays the coordinates in the leaflet map. It uses map.latlng.lng and map.latlng.lat, but I couldn't figure out, how to adapt the code to return a list with the coordinates instead of displaying them.

Ideally this code should work:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles()
  })

  output$out <- renderPrint({
    validate(need(input$map_mouseover, FALSE))
    str(input$map_mouseover)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`onRender`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/htmlwidgets/versions/1.0/topics/onRender) from `htmlwidgets`, you can add some javascript to pass the coordinates from [`mousemove`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-mousemove) to a Shiny input, based on [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html).

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("map"),
    br(),
    verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet()  %>%
            addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
            setView(-122.4105513,37.78250256, zoom = 12) %>%
            onRender(
                "function(el,x){
                    this.on('mousemove', function(e) {
                        var lat = e.latlng.lat;
                        var lng = e.latlng.lng;
                        var coord = [lat, lng];
                        Shiny.onInputChange('hover_coordinates', coord)
                    });
                    this.on('mouseout', function(e) {
                        Shiny.onInputChange('hover_coordinates', null)
                    })
                }"
            )
    })

    output$out <- renderText({
        if(is.null(input$hover_coordinates)) {
            "Mouse outside of map"
        } else {
            paste0("Lat: ", input$hover_coordinates[1], 
                   "\nLng: ", input$hover_coordinates[2])
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: how did you make that gif? It looks awesome!

Comment: @aspiringurbandatascientist thanks! there's probably an easier way, but  I take a screen recording with quicktime and then make a gif with picgif lite

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't R leaflet recognize `mousemove`? We should be able to:

```
observeEvent(input$map_mousemove, {

    coords <- unlist(input$map_mousemove)
})
```

And extract longitude and latitude accordingly.
This observer works with `click` event anyhow, which is also part of the [Map Interaction events](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-event)